# cypher alphabet to array - capitalized and grouped

Tags: c

I have been trying to get this program to work for like 10 hours, I am doing something wrong and I am still unsure why the program doesn't work. Every time I look up how to do it, it is a different  variation of what I am trying to do and when I try to modify it, it does not work. This program is supposed to take only letters of a text file and output them in groups of 5 letters, capitalized. What am I doing wrong here?Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    FILE * files;
    char notes[1000];
    int charcounter = 0, wordcounter = 0, c;
    files = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if(!files)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if(files)
    {
        while(fgets(notes, sizeof notes, files) != NULL)
        {
            size_t i, n = strlen(notes);

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            {
                if(isalpha(notes[i]))
                {
                    int c = toupper(notes[i]);
                    putchar(c);
                    if(wordcounter == 50)
                    {
                        printf("\n");
                        wordcounter = 0;
                    }

                    if(charcounter == 5)
                    {
                        printf(" ");
                        charcounter = 0;
                    }
                    wordcounter++;
                    charcounter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(files);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39802458/971127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking the value of the counters before you increment them.  Because of this, the counter starts at 0 on the first word but then starts at 1 on each subsequent word.  So on the first word you're capturing 6 letters instead of 5.

Do the increment first before the limit check.  Also, check `charcounter` before `wordcounter` so you don't have an extra space at the start of the second and subsequent lines:

```
wordcounter++;
charcounter++;
if(charcounter == 5)
{
    printf(" ");
    charcounter = 0;
}
if(wordcounter == 50) 
{
    printf("\n");
    wordcounter = 0;
}
```

Input file:

```
I am trying to see whether or not this works correctly this quick brown fox
jumps over the lazy dog. Hold it now, hold it now, hold it now, HIT IT!!
```

Output:

```
IAMTR YINGT OSEEW HETHE RORNO TTHIS WORKS CORRE CTLYT HISQU 
ICKBR OWNFO XJUMP SOVER THELA ZYDOG HOLDI TNOWH OLDIT NOWHO 
LDITN OWHIT IT
```

Comment: When I run the program, the screen pops up then closes really fast.. I cannot get an output at all, and I even did system("pause") to make the screen pause.. Did you add anything to the program to make it work differently?

Comment: @Submersed24-- You should replace `system("PAUSE")` with `getchar()` so that the output is visible until you press the Enter key.